# How to monitor DHCP traffic with Java?

Tags: java, linux, jsp, networking, dhcp

I am working on DHCP Billing System project. Only devices which administrators include their mac addresses can get ip address from DHCP. There are some mac addresses which belong to devices of former workers. I need monitor DHCP traffic and determine which mac addresses dont make request to get ip anymore. How can i do it?

Comment: One simple way I can think of is if you know Shell or perl commands, you can run them using Java.

Comment: You'll need to listen on port 67 and you'll only see `DHCPDISCOVER` and `DHCPREQUEST` messages because the responses are addressed directly to the MAC of the sender and won't be sent to your monitoring server by the switch. Don't know if you can get the requestor's MAC (which is in the ethernet header) from java so I'm not going to make this an answer. Might be better to use ARP instead.